# How to distribute signed outlook macro

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

With the deployment of Outlook 2010, my organization requires macros to be digitally signed (enforced by group policy on Macro Settings). I developed an Outlook Macro that I want to distribute in to several colleagues.

From intitial research, I believe that the actual project itself has to be signed. So this would most likely mean I would have to distribute by passing around the VBAProject.OTM. My colleagues aren't using any other VBA code, so that might be ok.

However, I wanted to see if there is a better way, or if there are other caveats I should be aware of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This TechNet article may help. [Deploy a Certificate by Using the Command Prompt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061(v=ws.10).aspx) You need to export the certificate that signed the macro first, then add it to root.

Comment: Thank you. The question I have, though, isn't about deploying the certificate. It's about deploying the actual Macro. My understanding is that you sign a *project* in Outlook, rather than a Macro. It seems like the only or perhaps just default project in Outlook is VBAProject.OTM, so I kind of wonder what the plan is if I write/use Macro A, and Bob writes/uses Macro B, and Mary wants to use both. How do they get distributed to Mary? Is a new or one-off signed projected containing both really the answer?

Comment: Even if you deployed the signed VBAProject.OTM to your machines, without Installing the Digital Cert on the computer to Trusted Root it won't run (unless your D.C. is signed by a trusted certificate authority). You can export and import modules via VBA under certain circumstances. Unless you can compile the Outlook macro to a dll/exe to add as Add-In, VBAProject.OTM is the only way to have those features.

Comment: May I suggest creating a DLL using VB6 instead? VBA in Outlook is a personal single-user deployment. You are better off simply sending a text file with your macro code and leave the code signing to each individual machine.